# Efficient use of Numpy to process in blocks of rows

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numpy

I need to iterate over a set of unique accounts (AccountID in the example code below) and calculate a selection of features for each unique AccountID (currently just showing TargetCol as an example). In reality, I am reading in a csv file as a Pandas dataframe (1M rows) and then converting to a Numpy records array so that I can still refer to the header names in the loops. The way I have approached this is to  create a slice for each unique AccountID, calculate TargetCol for each slice and then concatenate the slices back together.

The code I have below works ok but I am pretty sure it can be done in a much more efficient way (by efficient I mean reduced processing time).

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

x=300 #make x higher to test more records
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(x,3),columns=['AccountID','Bcol','Ccol'])
for m,row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[m,'AccountID'] = np.random.randint(int(x/10))
    df.loc[m,'Bcol'] = np.int(np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1000.0, size=None))/10000
    df.loc[m,'Ccol'] = np.int(np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1000.0, size=None))/10000

df['TargetCol']=np.nan
dfnum = df.to_records(index=False)
dfnum = np.sort(dfnum, order=['AccountID']) 
pd.DataFrame(dfnum)

uniquelist = np.unique(dfnum['AccountID'])
for u in range(0,len(uniquelist)):
    dfslice = dfnum[dfnum['AccountID'] == uniquelist[u]]
    for i in range(0,len(dfslice)):
        if (len(dfslice) - i) >= 6:
            dfslice['TargetCol'][i] = np.nansum(dfslice['Bcol'][i:i+6]) / dfslice['Ccol'][i]
        else:
            dfslice['TargetCol'][i] = np.NaN
    if u==0:
        dfconcat = dfslice
    else:
        dfconcat = np.concatenate((dfconcat, dfslice),axis=0)

pd.DataFrame(dfconcat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC I think you need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AccountID': [1,  1,       1, 2,   1,  2,  1,      2, 2],
                   'RefDay':    [1,  2,       3, 1,   4,  2,  5,      3, 4],
                   'BCol':      [1., 2., np.nan, 1., 3., 2., 1., np.nan, 2.] ,
                   'CCol':      [3., 2.,     3., 1., 3., 4., 5.,     2., 1.] })
df = df.sort_values(by=['AccountID','RefDay']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Replace with 6 in real data
periods = 3
result = df.groupby('AccountID').apply(lambda g: g['BCol'].fillna(0).rolling(periods).sum().shift(-periods + 1) / g['CCol'])
df['TargetColumn'] = result.sortlevel(1).values
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   AccountID  BCol  CCol  RefDay  TargetColumn
0          1   1.0   3.0       1      1.000000
1          1   2.0   2.0       2      2.500000
2          1   NaN   3.0       3      1.333333
3          1   3.0   3.0       4           NaN
4          1   1.0   5.0       5           NaN
5          2   1.0   1.0       1      3.000000
6          2   2.0   4.0       2      1.000000
7          2   NaN   2.0       3           NaN
8          2   2.0   1.0       4           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it is more clear if I add a RefDay column:

df = pd.DataFrame({'AccountID': [1,   1,      1,  2,  1,  2,  1,      2,  2],
                       'RefDay': [1,   2,      3,  1,  4,  2,  5,      3,  4],
                       'BCol':      [1., 2., np.nan, 1., 3., 2., 1., np.nan, 2.] ,
                       'CCol':      [3., 2., 3.,     1., 3., 4., 5.,     2., 1.] })
    df = df.sort_values(by=['AccountID','RefDay'])

With this, the TargetColumn values should be:
1|2.5|1.33|NaN|NaN|3|1|NaN|NaN

Comment: @GivenX Okay, I've added that, not sure if that is exactly what you need... Otherwise it might be better to have a complete example of input and expected output in the question.

Comment: Super elegant and super fast!  Thanks!