# Python Numpy efficient concatenation of slices

Tags: python, numpy

Referring to a question I posted previously: [Efficient use of Numpy to process in blocks of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929379/efficient-use-of-numpy-to-process-in-blocks-of-rows/50929854#50929854)

I got some good steers with pandas (thanks @jdehesa) but I really need to work with numpy. My main concern is around the way the slices are combined into one, i.e. the:

```
dfconcat = np.concatenate((dfconcat, dfslice),axis=0)
```

This seems like a super inefficient way of combining the slices, and I feel like this should be able to be done in one step outside of a loop (possibly by adding another dimension to the dfslice array that references each AccountID)? Is my approach generally on the right track or is there a much better way of doing this? Workings so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AccountID': [1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2],
                   'RefDay':    [1,2,3,1,4,2,5,3,4],
                   'BCol':      [1,2,np.nan,1,3,2,1,np.nan,2],
                   'CCol':      [3,2,3,1,3,4,5,2,1]})
df = df[['AccountID','RefDay','BCol','CCol']] #sorting out order

df['TargetCol']=np.nan
dfnum = df.to_records(index=False)
dfnum = np.sort(dfnum, order=['AccountID','RefDay']) #make sure the order is correct

uniquelist = np.unique(dfnum['AccountID'])
for u in range(0,len(uniquelist)):
    dfslice = dfnum[dfnum['AccountID'] == uniquelist[u]]
    for i in range(0,len(dfslice)):
        if (len(dfslice) - i) >= 3:
            dfslice['TargetCol'][i] = np.nansum(dfslice['BCol'][i:i+3]) / dfslice['CCol'][i]
        else:
            dfslice['TargetCol'][i] = np.NaN
    if u==0:
        dfconcat = dfslice
    else:
        dfconcat = np.concatenate((dfconcat, dfslice),axis=0)

pd.DataFrame(dfconcat)
```

OUT:

```
AccountID   RefDay  BCol    CCol    TargetCol
1           1       1.0     3       1.000000
1           2       2.0     2       2.500000
1           3       NaN     3       1.333333
1           4       3.0     3       NaN
1           5       1.0     5       NaN
2           1       1.0     1       3.000000
2           2       2.0     4       1.000000
2           3       NaN     2       NaN
2           4       2.0     1       NaN
```

Comment: You could collect all the `dfslice` into a list. And call `np.concatenate` on this list once outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have any experience of all with Panda.

First of all, I think with adding the additional axis you're certainly on the right track.

You could try creating the array in advance, so that it never has to be resized. Initialize the final array(lets call it myarray, since dfconcat will be misleading in a moment) as an array of DataFrames(if im correct and it's basically just a np.ndarray), with length len(uniquelist). This will prevent many resizes from happening, which may potentially cause it to be copied to a place with sufficient continuous memory. I think this is the biggest win you can make.

When doing this, you'll not use concatenate, but instead you can just assign: myarray[u] = dfslice, since you know you've got the correct number of elements. Or just write to the final array right away, skipping dfslice construction

**EDIT**: Code removed because it was incorrect, since the array would be to short. However, I can't figure out where you your code is being compensated for that. My apologies if that makes this answer a bit unclear. Important parts:
1) Grab the addtional axis
2) Create the array at full size before you fill it.

Answer (score 0):

First on the issue on `concatenate`, it is more efficient to collect values in a list, e.g. `alist.append(...)`. and create the array once at the end.  Repeated concatenates in a loop is slower.

---

Without using Pandas I think your `dfnum` array can be constructed as

```
In [162]: adict={'AccountID': [1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2],
     ...:                    'RefDay':    [1,2,3,1,4,2,5,3,4],
     ...:                    'BCol':      [1,2,np.nan,1,3,2,1,np.nan,2],
     ...:                    'CCol':      [3,2,3,1,3,4,5,2,1]}
     ...:                    
In [163]: 
In [163]: len(adict['CCol'])
Out[163]: 9

In [166]: arr = np.zeros(9, [('AccountID',int),('RefDay',int),('BCol',float),('CCol',int)])
In [167]: for n in arr.dtype.names:
     ...:     arr[n] = adict[n]
     ...:     
In [168]: arr
Out[168]: 
array([(1, 1,  1., 3), (1, 2,  2., 2), (1, 3, nan, 3), (2, 1,  1., 1),
       (1, 4,  3., 3), (2, 2,  2., 4), (1, 5,  1., 5), (2, 3, nan, 2),
       (2, 4,  2., 1)],
      dtype=[('AccountID', '<i8'), ('RefDay', '<i8'), ('BCol', '<f8'), ('CCol', '<i8')])

In [171]: dfnum = np.sort(arr, order=['AccountID','RefDay'])
In [174]: np.unique(dfnum['AccountID'], return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
Out[174]: (array([1, 2]), array([0, 5]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
```

here's your loop without list append.

```
In [182]: alist =[]; targets=[]
     ...: for u in range(0,len(uniquelist)):
     ...:     dfslice = dfnum[dfnum['AccountID'] == uniquelist[u]]
     ...:     target = np.zeros(len(dfslice))
     ...:     for i in range(0,len(dfslice)):
     ...:         if (len(dfslice) - i) >= 3:
     ...:             target[i] = np.nansum(dfslice['BCol'][i:i+3]) / dfslice['C
     ...: Col'][i]
     ...:         else:
     ...:             target[i] = np.NaN
     ...:     alist.append(dfslice)
     ...:     targets.append(target)
     ...:     
     ...:     
In [183]: alist
Out[183]: 
[array([(1, 1,  1., 3), (1, 2,  2., 2), (1, 3, nan, 3), (1, 4,  3., 3),
        (1, 5,  1., 5)],
       dtype=[('AccountID', '<i8'), ('RefDay', '<i8'), ('BCol', '<f8'), ('CCol', '<i8')]),
 array([(2, 1,  1., 1), (2, 2,  2., 4), (2, 3, nan, 2), (2, 4,  2., 1)],
       dtype=[('AccountID', '<i8'), ('RefDay', '<i8'), ('BCol', '<f8'), ('CCol', '<i8')])]
In [184]: targets
Out[184]: 
[array([1.        , 2.5       , 1.33333333,        nan,        nan]),
 array([ 3.,  1., nan, nan])]
```

I missed the addition of the `TargetCol` field, so had to fudge with `target`.

```
In [185]: np.concatenate(alist)
Out[185]: 
array([(1, 1,  1., 3), (1, 2,  2., 2), (1, 3, nan, 3), (1, 4,  3., 3),
       (1, 5,  1., 5), (2, 1,  1., 1), (2, 2,  2., 4), (2, 3, nan, 2),
       (2, 4,  2., 1)],
      dtype=[('AccountID', '<i8'), ('RefDay', '<i8'), ('BCol', '<f8'), ('CCol', '<i8')])
In [186]: np.concatenate(targets)
Out[186]: 
array([1.        , 2.5       , 1.33333333,        nan,        nan,
       3.        , 1.        ,        nan,        nan])
```

I was thinking that with the added outputs of `Out[174]` I could get by without the loop, but I haven't worked out the details.